# RMarkdown in Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, knitr

## Problem

Is there a way to insert (and evaluate) an RMarkdown script in a shiny application. (Note, I am not looking for a shiny application in RMarkdown that is explained [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html), nor am I looking for Markdown scripts in shiny ([see Shiny Gallery Markdown](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/including-html-text-and-markdown-files.html)))

I am building an application that has text, equations, code-chunks, plots, and interactive elements. For convenience I use Markdown files for the text and equations and would like to have a plot sometimes in between (i.e. write most stuff in RMarkdown). As the shiny-app is more complex (I use `shinydashboard` including many of its unique features), I would prefer an option that does not use the approach described in the [first link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

A minimum working example would be:

R-file:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    includeMarkdown("RMarkdownFile.rmd")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and "RMarkdownFile.rmd" in the same folder:

````
This is a text

$$ E(x) = 0 $$ 

```{r, eval = T}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

## Result:

[image: Shiny App]

## Target

What I want to have is the output if I knit the `rmd`-file:
[image: RMarkdown HTML page]

Specifically, I want to get the evaluation of the code-chunks (plot something...), and I want to get the rendered math equations.

Any ideas?

## Edited Solution

Thanks to  the input of @Bunk, I chose to render all `rmd` files to `md` files with the command `knit` and then include the `md` files in the shiny app (I use markdown instead of html as the latter produced some issues with equations). Lastly, the `includeMarkdown` is wrapped in `withMathJax` to ensure the proper display of equations.

The final code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

rmdfiles <- c("RMarkdownFile.rmd")
sapply(rmdfiles, knit, quiet = T)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        withMathJax(includeMarkdown("RMarkdownFile.md"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your solution works better for me. Would you mind posting it as a proper answer?

Comment: Sure, see below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think knitting it and rendering a UI should work.

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        uiOutput('markdown')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$markdown <- renderUI({
        HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('RMarkdownFile.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good idea, I was just playing around with `includeHTML` after using `knitr` to create a HTML file.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, you could probably render as the application loads and do that instead.  Doing this allows you to evaluate the code chunks in specific environments.  I don't know if that is useful in this case.

Comment: One more question though, does your equation render properly?

Comment: yea it does for me, I ran it on firefox.  I think you just need to make sure that the mathjax script is getting loaded.

Comment: you could mess around with the `withMathJax()` function.

Comment: @David sorry, it looks like your edit was rejected since I was on here, I would have accepted it.  One thing I would change, instead of setting working directory, use a relative path if possible.

Answer (score 13):

As per @elevendollar's request, this is what I ended up using:

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

rmdfiles <- c("file1.Rmd", "file2.Rmd")
mdfiles <- gsub("Rmd$", "md", rmdfiles)

a <- lapply(rmdfiles, knit, quiet = T)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    withMathJax(
      # loop over the files and create one tabPanel for each file
      do.call(tabsetPanel,
              lapply(mdfiles, function(f) tabPanel(f, includeMarkdown(f))))
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You used `sapply` so I presumed it works for more than 1 length of `rmdfiles`. But in the `includeMarkdown("RMarkdownFile.md"))` you use a hardcoded file name. Why?  
Can you please make it a vector to make the answer complete for a more general vector scenario ? Thanks

Comment: Better late than never; done!