# shiny mainPanel width when including markdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to include a "reactive" `.Rmd` file within a shiny application. It would summarize the user's choices and various conditions that arise. For whatever reason, I find including `shiny` *within* `.Rmd` [documented](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html), but not including the ability to knit `.Rmd` and have the output included inside a `shiny` app.

I find these very hard to reproduce, so here's my attempt using the [hello world](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/) example from Rstudio. Here's the app as-is in chromium:

[image: full-size]

Next, I add a `uiOutput` element to `ui.R`:

```
# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot"),
  uiOutput("mark")
)
```

I also add a corresponding output in `server.R`, taken from this sort of similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499651/rmarkdown-in-shiny-application):

```
output$mark <- renderUI({

  HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit("./test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE)))

})
```

The contents of `test.Rmd` are this:

````
## something to print

```{r}

head(mtcars, input$bins)

```
````

When I run it, I now get this (screenshot footprint is the same):

[image: cramped]

I'm assuming there's some `css` or something in the knit document that's goofing things up, but I don't know. I can force the widths wider, but the main panel stays sort of centered.

---

I've tried `includeMarkdown` but wasn't able to get it to update based on `input`. Keep in mind that's the eventual hope -- I need something that can regenerate whatever is displayed based on changed `input` values. I realize I could do `renderText` or something, but the `Rmarkdown` format is so convenient as this is sort of a guide. I can write some documentation, then show the user what they've selected and what happens as a result.

It seems close... I just can't figure out why the page goes wonky.

I also tried stuff like `style = "width: 1200px"` or `style = "width: 100%"` without being able to get the ratio between the `sidebarPanel` and `mainPanel` back to normal.

Ideally, the output would look just like the original, but the knit results would show up under the current footprint of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the rmd code adds the following property to the `body` element:

```
max-width: 800px;
```

To remove this, add the following to your ui code (for example below `sliderInput`)

```
     tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                               body {
                                  width: 100% !important;
                                  max-width: 100% !important;
                               }

                               ")))
```

Comment: Genius! How did you find that?? I searched the source on the shiny app and didn't see it. I did just now knit the `test.Rmd` file and I see `.main-container { max-width: 940px; }`. This works like a charm. Now that I know what I'm looking for, I was even able to control for just one `output`: `div[id = blah] { max-width: 100% !important; }` for example. Sincere thanks for the quick investigation.

Comment: I normally use the `Inspect element` context menu of Firefox to find out the style related to each element. Very easy and convenient to use.

Answer (score 2):

Set `fragment.only=TRUE` in `markdownToHTML`:

```
output$mark <- renderUI({

  HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit("./test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE), fragment.only=TRUE))

})
```