# could not find bibliography file: citations.bib in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm having trouble with `rmarkdown::render()` recognizing a `.bib` file. I've tried putting it in the `www` file and also the directory from which the app is run with no success. I've had success locally by adding `/users/blah/blah/citations.bib` but when deploying this workaround it doesn't work (as it shouldn't). I've also looked into this [Bibliography not working when rendering a R Markdown document within an R Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368840/bibliography-not-working-when-rendering-a-r-markdown-document-within-an-r-shiny), which works great for static htmls produced prior to deploying; however, my case involves the user creating a unique report while deployed and nullifies this option (I think...). Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.