# Cannot get png picture in rmd file to be displayed in r Shiny app

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I hope you all had a good summer!

I am currently building my first r Shiny app ever. Among other things, I have incorporated an rmd-file, which contains an image (png).

Unfortunately, the Shiny app does not display this image. Instead, I get this:

I have tried the following code chunks(the picture is sitting in the same folder as my rmd file):

```
knitr::include_graphics("knn.png")
```

```
magick::image_read("knn.png")
```

Whenever I knit to html, the pictures are included in the output, but they are not shown in the Shiny app (as explained above).

Can somebody tell me how I can get the picture to show up in the Shiny app?

Many thanks in advance,
Andrea

Comment: Your image attachment didn't make it into your question. Please upload and embed image.

Answer (score 0):

#### RMD

Here is a minimal example of an Rmarkdown that contains two images. One is embedded with markdown syntax and another one is created with `plot()`. We can render this RMD to HTML (test1.html).

````
---
title: "RMD with a png"
output: html_document
date: "2023-09-12"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r eval=FALSE}
# Run this once manually to create pic.png
png("pic.png")
plot(mtcars)
dev.off()
```

![](pic.png)

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```
````

#### Shiny

This is a minimal shiny example that embeds the HTML generated from the RMD into the UI by with `shiny::includeHTML()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Include RMarkdown"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          includeHTML("test1.html")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Make sure that all files are in the same folder as the app. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499651/rmarkdown-in-shiny-application) to render the RMD within the app.

Comment: Hi Till, thanks a lot for your prompt and thorough reply, I really appreciate your help! Before getting to see your reply, I got it to work by using ![](pic.png) (instead of knitr::include_graphics()) and by moving my png from a sub-folder back to the main folder. Nonetheless, thanks again for your help! Have a lovely day!